# js input onBlur not worked when the page onload

Tags: javascript, onblur

The link example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/fxr5p/ How to make if value is empty, onload work `onblur` function? show `type your keyword`, then click the input part, `onblur` word disapear? Thanks.

```
<input type="text" value=""  id="search" name="Search" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='type your keyword';" onfocus="if(this.value=='type your keyword') this.value='';">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
  document.body.onload = function ()
  {
    document.getElementById("search").value = "type your keyword";
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" value="type your keyword"  id="search" name="Search" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='type your keyword';" onfocus="if(this.value=='type your keyword') this.value='';">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're almost there, just use `value="type your keyword"`.